# Are the indexes in Arrays.copyOfRange correct?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not sure if I understand something wrong, for the util `Arrays.copyOfRange(array,from,to)` , supposed that we want to slice from the 3th element to the last element, I have to do like this:

```
a = {3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10};

b = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,3,6);
```

Which produce `{6,9,10}`. In my opinion, this does not make sense.

I think if we're talking about the index, the index of the last element should be 5,  which is  `Arrays.copyOfRange(a,3,5).`

In the case if we're talking about the position, it should be `Arrays.copyOfRange(a,2,5).`

Otherwise it should throw the `ArrayOutOfBoundException.`

So the question here is that was the function bad written? , or I understand something wrong?

Comment: Read the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int[],%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: Using an exclusive end value makes it easier for `start + length` to be used for things like this; they could also have chosen to use  `(start, length)`, but that is less logical when something is called `copyOfRange`.

Comment: sure I've read API @Mena

Answer (score 3):

The last parameter can be outside the bounds, e.g. larger than the array size as the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) state:

> to - the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive. (This index may lie outside the array.)

and the `to` is exclusive meaning that `Arrays.copyOfRange(a,3,6)` will return the elements at the positions 3, 4 and 5 - the element at 6 will not be present.

Additionally

> Throws:
>   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if from < 0 or from > original.length

Your assumption *"Otherwise it should throw the ArrayOutOfBoundException"* is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these indexes as offsets. Same is true for `String.substring()` and many others.

With offsets in mind, imagine it like a pointer *between* elements. So for instance:

```
[ 2, 6, 1, 3 ]
```

offset 0 would be

```
[ 2, 6, 1, 3 ]
 ^
```

Now, if you want elements `[6, 1]` the offsets would be

```
[ 2, 6, 1, 3 ]
    ^     ^
```

which is indexes 1-3.